# Returning a document with two fields from the same array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given documents such as

```
{
  _id: 'abcd',
  userId: '12345',
  activities: [
    { status: 'login', timestamp: '10000001' },
    { status: 'logout', timestamp: '10000002' },
    { status: 'login', timestamp: '10000003' },
    { status: 'logout', timestamp: '10000004' },
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create a pipeline such as all users that have their latest login/logout activities recorded between two timestamps will be returned. For example, if the two timestamp values are between `10000002` and `10000003`, the expected document should be

```
{
  _id: 'abcd',
  userId: '12345',
  login: '10000003',
  logout: '10000002'
}
```

Of if the two timestamp values are between `-1` and `10000001`, the expected document should be :

```
{
  _id: 'abcd',
  userId: '12345',
  login: '10000001',
  logout: null
}
```

Etc.

I know it has to do with aggregations, and I need to `$unwind`, etc., but I'm not sure about the rest, namely evaluating two fields from the same document array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { 
        $unwind: "$activities" 
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { "activities.timestamp": { $gte: "10000001" } },
                { "activities.timestamp": { $lte: "10000002" } }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "activities.timestamp": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            userId: { $first: "$userId" },
            activities: { $push: "$activities" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            login: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$activities", as: "a", cond: { $eq: [ "$$a.status", "login" ] } } } , 0 ] },
            logout: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$activities", as: "a", cond: { $eq: [ "$$a.status", "logout" ] } } } , 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            userId: 1,
            login: { $ifNull: [ "$login.timestamp", null ] },
            logout: { $ifNull: [ "$logout.timestamp", null ] }
        }
    }
])
```

We need to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) + [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) + [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to make sure that our activities will be sorted by timestamp. After `$unwind` you can use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to apply filtering condition. Then you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get first (latest) value of filtered array. In the last `$project` you can explicitly use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) (otherwise JSON key will be skipped if there's no value)

Comment: I have an issue with this query; the `$gte` and `$lte` on the same field only returns one document from the collection.

Comment: @YanickRochon could you send me the mongoplayground with your data (https://mongoplayground.net/) ?

Comment: I have tried the query I have on mongoplayground et it returns the expected result. Yet, the mongo driver I use does not. The version I have is 3.6.4 and mongoplaygroud uses 4.0.3.

Comment: Right, I understood the issue; some timestamps are stored as strings, while others as ISODate objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

Instead of [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) use [**`$lte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/) and [**`$gte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) with the [**`$fitler`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "userId": 1,
    "login": {
      "$max": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$activities",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              { "$gte": ["$$this.timestamp", "10000001"] },
              { "$lte": ["$$this.timestamp", "10000004"] },
              { "$lte": ["$$this.status", "login"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "logout": {
      "$max": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$activities",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              { "$gte": ["$$this.timestamp", "10000001"] },
              { "$lte": ["$$this.timestamp", "10000004"] },
              { "$lte": ["$$this.status", "logout"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to sort `activities` before fetching `$arrayElemAt`? Because if the timestamp range is large, and if there are multiple "logout" activities, what guarantees that the most recent one will be returned? (Idem for "login".)

Comment: @YanickRochon Updated my answer. You can use [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator with the timestamp to get the latest record from the array. Now can achieve this with single aggregation stage even.